# Android Phonegap: best way to store and process arrays

Tags: android, cordova

It seems that phonegaps documentation is rather limited in terms of what it assumes are good coding practises and bad ones. What in your experience is the best way to store arrays for processing using phonegaps api: 
i) database
ii) Writing to file
Please explain why and please answer even if you have a suggestion not mentioned in the options above.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on situation, 
there are many ways to save set of data like arrays and ... in my opinion if you have some static data (which will not changed during run-time) its good idea to save them inside string.xml (stored in res folder) or if your data has some structure that can not be saved in strings.xml so you can hold them in a separated xml file inside raw folder, but if you have dynamic data there are other ways like database (easy and fast) or in separated files (xml, text).